# Can't seem to get form values (in view) to the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, view, models

I have 2 bits of code here.

This is my controller at the moment:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebMatrix.Data;

namespace Best_prototype_01.Controllers
{
    public class RecrutaController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

            protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
                // Sender e-mail address.
                Msg.From = new MailAddress(txtEmail.Text);
                // Recipient e-mail address.
                Msg.To.Add("administrator@aspdotnet-suresh.com");
                Msg.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
                Msg.Body = txtMessage.Text;
                // your remote SMTP server IP.
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("yourgmailemail@gmail.com", "yourpassword");
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(Msg);
                //Msg = null;
                lbltxt.Text = "Thanks for Contact us";
                // Clear the textbox valuess
                txtName.Text = "";
                txtSubject.Text = "";
                txtMessage.Text = "";
                txtEmail.Text = "";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

And this is the view that's supposedly associated with it (the part that matters anyways):

```
<form id="form1"  >
    <div>
        <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="0">
            <tr><td></td><td><b>Contact Us Form</b></td></tr>
            <tr><td><b>Name</b></td><td><asp:TextBox ID="txtName"   /></td></tr>
            <tr><td><b>Email</b></td><td><asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail"   /></td></tr>
            <tr><td><b>Subject</b></td><td><asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject"   /></td></tr>
            <tr><td valign="top"><b>Message</b></td><td> <asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" Rows="5" Columns="40" TextMode="MultiLine"   /></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td><asp:button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit"   onclick="btnSubmit_Click" CssClass="Button" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2" style=" color:red"><asp:Label ID="lbltxt"   /></td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? I have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: This is web forms code, not asp.net-mvc! There are no events in MVC. Suggest you go to the MVC site and learn the basics.

Comment: Calm the hell down bro, not everyone is a master at programming, I'm new and I'm doing my best to learn, how about actually helping me out instead of taking the piss?

Comment: Yes, @Ruben Pereira, please go through `asp.net-mvc` basics first http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_intro.asp

Comment: Why is it so hard to explain something? If it's so "basic" then please explain what I'm doing wrong, I came here to learn not get smashed on.

Comment: Here is not a class room or a hint website. No one's job is to explain things to you. Did you research your issue? Looks like you didn't. Once you have a clear error then you come and post it here (if the question doesn't exist already)

Comment: Wow, seriously? This is the community huh? I'll have you know that I have done research but apparently the words "I'M NEW AT THIS" are to difficult to understand. I asked for advice, not a solution as in I was expecting someone to say "You did x wrong, try looking up y". But no, I get told to learn the basics (which I did, I even watched a 9 hour course made by Scott Allen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have `xyz_Click()` events in your controller. What you have are so-called `ActionResult`s
What you need is
a) define the target action in your form on your view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("NameOfYour ActionResult", "NameOfController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @name = "someformname"}))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
//your form code with inputs, combos etc.
```

The AntiForgeryToken secures against cross-site-posting by the way.

Then in your controller create the ActionResult:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult NameOfYourActionResult(FormCollection fcol)
{
//your form evaluation goes here. All your form data is accessible through fcol, e.g. like this:
//Msg.From = new MailAddress(fcol["txtEmail"]);
```

Aside from that: yes, please learn about MVC basics first. It is quite a bit different to Web Forms. [w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_intro.asp](http://w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_intro.asp)

Comment: Thanks, I have now figured out what I was doing wrong, I didn't even knew Web Forms was a totally different thing from MVC.